# Search predicate for searching first and last name in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, predicate

Imagine the following contact:

```
{
  first_name:"Walter",
  last_name:"White"
}
```

I would like the following search strings to return that contact:

- `Walter White`
- `White Walter`

However, the above search strings should not return the following contacts:

```
{
  first_name:"Skylar",
  last_name:"White"
}

{
  first_name:"Walter",
  last_name:"Grey"
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this by writing an sqlite predicate.

I'm thinking that this must be a very common problem, but I haven't found a question here that answers this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name = ?
   OR last_name || ' ' || first_name = ?
```

Comment: That's what I've implemented (except I use LIKE instead of =), but it doesn't work with double names.

Comment: @ErikB If you mean names like "Mary Sue Jones", as long as you keep Mary and Sue in the correct order, CL's answer should do the trick. e.g. Only "Jones Mary Sue" and "Mary Sue Jones" are correct searches, but not "Jones Sue Mary".

Comment: @Maple Yes, but the problem is that it doesn't work for "Mary Jones".

Comment: @ErikB You're talking about doing partial matches then. e.g. Mich returns Michael, Walt returns Walter, Mary returns Mary Sue, etc.

Comment: @ErikB Building off CL's, I've got a solution below that solves for the double name problem.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the comments in CL's answer: 
You're talking about doing partial matches. e.g. Mich returns Michael, Walt returns Walter, Mary returns Mary Sue, etc.

**EDIT:**

Using a little reverse LIKE trickery and some input padding, you get this:

```
SELECT *
FROM People_Table
WHERE first_name || ' ' last_name LIKE '%' || (SELECT replace(inputString, ' ', '%')) || '%'
   OR last_name || ' ' first_name LIKE '%' || (SELECT replace(inputString, ' ', '%')) || '%'
```

For double names like "Mary Sue Jones", the following will all match:
"Mary Jones", "Jones", "Sue Jones", "Jones Sue", "Sue Mary", "Mary Sue Jones", etc.
The drawback to this method is that if the portions of a double name are out of order in the search string, it will not match. You'll have to go outside this SQLite predicate to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

First Separate & then search for  FirstName = firstname and LastName = lastname and then reverse just in case if the User types in the last name first

```
try {       
    int firstSpace = search_str.indexOf(" "); // detect the first space character
    firstName = search_str.substring(0, firstSpace);  // get everything upto the first space character
    lastName = search_str.substring(firstSpace).trim(); // get everything after the first space, trimming the spaces off
        }
catch (Exception c){}
```

FIRST_NAME LIKE '%"+firstName+"%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%"+lastName+"%'  OR FIRST_NAME LIKE '%"+lastName+"%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%"+firstName+"%'